# how to handle multiple regression with indepndent variables are categorical as well as continous?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, ordinal-data, categorical-encoding

I have dependent variable ( Y) is in continuous.

My independent variables ( X1 , X2 , X3, X4,  X5, X6, X7, X8) are in continuous.

And independent variables ( X9 , X10 ) are categorical variables.

In X9, there have 3 levels ( TV , News Paper , Radio )

In X10 there have 2 levels ( High Addicted , Low Addicted).

So, How can I work with this kind of data in multiple regression analysis?

Comment: @StudentT, Like for X9 I have create a dummy variables  X91 for Tv ,  and X92 for News Paper .   same for X101 for High Addicted. right?

Comment: Have you taken a look at GAMs? They train models on both discreet and continuous variables separately and combine these models to make the final prediction. Also you can think about binning the continuous variables.

Comment: @saharudra , No I dont know abour GAMs, how it's works? for GAMs I need to create a alogorithm?

Comment: Search for generalized additive models